# How to create solana transaction from data array in js?

Tags: javascript, solana, solana-web3js, solana-transaction-instruction

Using an API I get the tx data needed to send a transaction to buy a NFT, and I have to turn that transaction data array into a Transaction, I tried using new `solanaWeb3.Transaction().from()` but I get a "Function not defined" error, any help? I use plain js btw

Comment: `Transaction` is a type, and not a function, so try `new solanaWeb3.Transaction.from()`

Comment: doesnt work, i get : Uncaught TypeError: solanaWeb3.Transaction.from is not a constructor

Comment: Ah right, sorry, you can remove `new`.